# Objective C / C static method performance

Tags: objective-c, c, performance, methods, static

Here is a method from a class in some of Apple's [example code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010048). Why is this method defined as a static C method rather than an Objective C class method or a class method? In the context in which it is used I suppose it needs to be as performant as possible. Is this why? Is this the most performant way to declare a method?

```
static BOOL lineIntersectsRect(MKMapPoint p0, MKMapPoint p1, MKMapRect r)
{
    //Do stuff
    return MKMapRectIntersectsRect(r, r2);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a static method, but rather a function. And it's probably defined as a function because it operates on two data types (`MKMapPoint` and `MKMapRect`) which are not objects (they are C structs) and thus can't have methods associated with them.

Comment: +1. A simple (and maybe stupid) question. Is it possible to use objects within static functions? Thanks.

Comment: @flexaddicted: Yes, but you won't be able to work with instance variables (since there's not an instance or even a class associated with functions).

Answer (score 2):

C functions are faster than Objective C methods because C functions bypass the Objective C runtime messaging system. The `static` keyword in the declaration limits the visibility of the function to the current compilation unit, so it is only visible in that particular file. The compiler can take a hint from the `static` keyword to optimize the assembler output for the function, so it is possible to increase performance further.